# An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in

Tags: c#

I got the following model:

```
public class ContentModels
    {
        public ContentModels(int _id, string _content, string _weight, string _language, string _country, string _location, string _os, string _browser, string _type, DateTime _startDate, DateTime _endDate)
        {
            id = _id;
            content = _content;
            weight = _weight;
            language = _language;
            country = _country;
            location = _location;
            os = _os;
            browser = _browser;
            type = _type;
            startDate = _startDate;
            endDate = _endDate;
        }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string content { get; set; }
    public string weight { get; set; }
    public string language { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
    public string os { get; set; }
    public string browser { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public DateTime startDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime endDate { get; set; }
}
```

And the following piece of code in my controller:

```
ContentModels content = new ContentModels(
Int32.Parse(reader["id"].ToString()),
reader["content"].ToString(),
reader["weight"].ToString(),
reader["language"].ToString(),
reader["country"].ToString(),
reader["location"].ToString(),
reader["os"].ToString(),
reader["Browser"].ToString(),
reader["Type"].ToString(),
(DateTime) reader["startDate"],
(DateTime)reader["endDate"]
);
```

which is pretty much supposed to query my database and create a new object based on the model. My database looks like this: `https://i.gyazo.com/d9e69fecf0e2117397819a665c665e03.png`

When I run the code I get the following error: `https://i.gyazo.com/bcc33a414f46df9906dc046fc714ef65.png`

Could someone point out my mistake?

Comment: It would be easier to diagnose if you used local variables rather than all of that casting and conversion inlined in the constructor call.  Are the `startDate` and `endDate` columns data columns in your database or _string_ columns that represent dates?

Comment: One or both of `reader["startDate"]` and `reader["endDate"]` is not a `DateTime`.

Comment: reader["startDate" or reader["endDate"] may be null, this is not allowed in C# DateTime.

Comment: This is the design: https://i.gyazo.com/295c5d218c69a294a974bdd2757c3e25.png They are not null as I filled in the date my my database.

Comment: Please don't use externally linked images, as 1) the networks are not necessarily available to everyone based on filtering 2) the links may die eventually, making most of the question useless, as we aren't getting the actual content of the question to reference.

Comment: as seen in your image, visual studio has automatically opened [The Debugger](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-A-Beginn) for you and made a breakpoint in the place where your error is occurring.  You might be able to use the debugger to determine what type `reader["startDate"]` and `reader["endDate"]` are

Comment: I might add to @SamIam 's answer that you can also use the immediate window in Visual Studio to interact with your code while stopped at the breakpoint.